# Using Stripe Connect - Can Stripe payements be used without being a Stripe member

Tags: stripe-payments

I am creating a site that will need a payment gateway to split payments for sellers when a buyer buys an item from the seller.

I have found out with Stripe Connect you can split payments which is great, but does anyone know if a buyer wants to buy an item from the seller, do the buyer and seller need a Stripe account or can the buyer and seller send and receive money without a Stripe account?

I was going to use PayPal Chained Adaptive Payments but found out that this service is depreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Stipe Connect there are multiple parties involved:

- The platform account, that's the main Stripe account
- The connected accounts, these are the sellers that are connected to the platform account. Each connected account need a Stripe account (either [Standard, Express, or Custom](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts))
- The customers who will buy the products, they don't need a Stripe account